# view function in cakePHP not working with a variable other than $id

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to pass a variable other than $id for a view function in my 'Texts' controller:

```
public function view($postid = NULL) {
        $this->Text->postid = $postid;
        $this->set('text', $this->Text->read());
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What route are you requesting? Are you passing an integer?

Comment: A am not getting an error, just nothing is being output.

@jnr - I am passing a string.

Comment: But does your string contain anything besides numeric digits? Because that's what the default routes expect.

Comment: @jnr - yes, it's letters and numbers. I'm new to cakePHP maybe you can tell me how to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Actually, nevermind. I was thinking of the REST routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
public function view($postid = NULL) { 
$post = $this->Text->find('first', array('conditions' => 
                                          array('Text.postid'=>$postid))); 
$this->set('text', $post); 
}
```

Comment: If you solved your question, mark your answer as solution, please.

Answer (score 1):

what are you doing there?
you can use read only with the primary key - id usually

```
$this->Text->id = $postid;
```

Comment: Okay. What should I use instead?

Comment: Figured it out:

    public function view($postid = NULL) {
  $post = $this->Text->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Text.postid'=>$postid)));
        $this->set('text', $post);
 }

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Is the `$primaryKey` property of your `Text` model set to `'postid'`? If not, then `$this->Text->read()` is not going to work like you want. In `app/Model/Text.php`, add this to your class:

```
public $primaryKey = 'postid';
```

You could also do the following if you don't want to change your primary key (but you probably should change it):

```
$text = $this->Text->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('postid' => $postid),
));
$this->set('text', $text);
```

Also, try adding something like this to your view to see what's actually in your variable:

```
<pre><?php var_dump($text); ?></pre>
```

That might give you a better idea of what's going on.

Lastly, here's some relevant documentation:

- [Model Attributes](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html)
- [Retrieving Your Data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your view function as:

```
public function view($name = NULL) {
    $record = $this->Text->findByName($name);        
    $this->set('text', $record);
}
```

Here `name` is a string. The `name` field should be present in the database.
You can see the content of $record by debugging.debug($record).